# Filter for ISI Channel

Tags: filter-design, ofdm

I know that OFDM has many advantages in removing ISI. But I think there is one more way of removing ISI(equalizing or inverting technique).

Syppose there is a channel $H(\omega)$ and we have our message $X(\omega)$.
So, the received signal will be
$$Y(\omega) = H(\omega)X(\omega)$$

So at the receiver end, we can just use a filter with $\frac{1}{H(\omega)}$.

Why don't we use an inverted filter here to avoid ISI?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

We do. It's called *Zero-Forcing Equalization*, and its disadvantages are very well-covered in literature.

Noise amplification!